# Looping over array in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjPh4.png)these is my input array(service_item_list)
...

```
for (var k = 0; k < service_item_list.length; k++) {
            for (var l = 0; l < service_item_list[k].length; l++) {
                service_item_list[k][l].service_id=this.state.selected_services[k].id
            }
        }



service_item_list=[[{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''}],[{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''}]]

this.state.selected_services=[{id:'5',event_id:'1'},{id:'6',event_id:'1'}]
```

...
i keep getting the output :
...

```
service_item_list=[[{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''}],[{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''}]]
```

...
but i need the output :
...

```
 service_item_list=[[{event_id:'1',service_id:'5',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'5',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'5',product_id:''}],[{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''},{event_id:'1',service_id:'6',product_id:''}]]
```

...
I'm not able to find where the error is???

Answer (score 0):

You can make things easier using JavaScript array map method. So the approach will be like this:

```
const service_item_list=[[{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''}],[{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''},{event_id:'',service_id:'',product_id:''}]]

const selected_services=[{id:'5',event_id:'1'},{id:'6',event_id:'1'}]

const res = service_item_list.map((arr, outerIdx) => {
    return arr.map((obj) => {
        obj.service_id = selected_services[outerIdx].id
        return obj;
    })
})

console.log(res)

[
    [
        { event_id: '', service_id: '5', product_id: '' },
        { event_id: '', service_id: '5', product_id: '' },
        { event_id: '', service_id: '5', product_id: '' },
    ],
    [
        { event_id: '', service_id: '6', product_id: '' },
        { event_id: '', service_id: '6', product_id: '' },
        { event_id: '', service_id: '6', product_id: '' },
    ],
];
```

The value stored in the res constant will be your result as shown above. More on JS array map method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)